# How can we update multiple columns in a smartsheet at a time using smartsheet C# SDK?

Tags: c#, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2

How can we update multiple columns in a smartsheet at a time using smartsheet C# SDK? We can update one column using UpdateColumn() API. How to update multiple column by one method?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe the Smartsheet API currently supports updating multiple columns in a single API request (and therefore this functionality isn't available in the C# SDK). You'll need to issue a separate request (i.e., call the `UpdateColumn()` method in the C# SDK) for each column you want to update.

Comment: The above is correct. The Smartsheet API does not currently support making updates to multiple columns at once in a single request. Multiple requests would need to be made and the UpdateColumn method would need to be used multiple times.